# Maven surefire plugin fails to pick correct testng suite.xml file

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have the following setup in my pom.xml:-

```
    <groupId>co.uk.me-test.project</groupId>
<artifactId>my-test-project
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <sl4j.version>1.7.7</sl4j.version>
    <suiteFile>src/test/resources/testproject/testng_suiteone.xml</suiteFile>
    <suiteFile>src/test/resources/testproject/testng_suitetwo.xml</suiteFile>
    <suiteFile>src/test/resources/testproject/testng_suitethree.xml</suiteFile>
    <suiteFile>src/test/resources/testproject/testng_suitefour.xml</suiteFile>
    <suiteFile>src/test/resources/testproject/testng_suitefive.xml</suiteFile>
    <suiteFile>src/test/resources/testproject/testng_suitesix.xml</suiteFile>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>-->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>parallel</name>
                        <value>methods</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>threadCount</name>
                        <value>1</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                        <value>1</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

At runtime, I am invoking the tests with the following goal:-

`mvn clean install -DsuiteXmlFile=testng_suitethree.xml`

I have an identical (seemingly) project which picks the correct suite.xml file dependent on the suite name passed in as a goal. Why then, does this project always pick suitesix.xml no matter if I pass in a different one?  If I comment out all suite files except the one I want THEN it runs it.  How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: It is called `suiteFile`, but you're passing `suiteXmlFile`... And why are you overriding `<suiteFile>` 5 times in the properties section?

Comment: @tunaki, you're right I was passing the wrong argument.  What I want to achieve is to be able to call the required testng suite file ar runtime - what other way can I do it if I don't list the available files in the properties section?

Comment: Sorry, I have worked this out now. CLosing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<properties>
    <suiteFile>{suiteFile}</suiteFile>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

mvn clean test  -D**surefire.suiteXmlFiles**=testng.xml > out.log

This will work.